# Object file not created after building

Tags: eclipse, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

I am getting an error when I am compiling my project on Eclipse Kepler.
The project builds successfully, but the object is unsuccessfully created.
I am getting the following output on my console

```
23:13:32 **** Build of configuration Debug for project Dictionary ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/Diction.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MM -MMD -MP -MF"src/Diction.d"       -MT"src/Diction.d" -o "src/Diction.o" "../src/Diction.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/Diction.cpp

Building target: Dictionary
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "Dictionary"  ./src/Diction.o   
./src/Diction.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Dictionary] Error 1

23:13:32 Build Finished (took 69ms)
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hello World project will not compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203032/hello-world-project-will-not-compile). Please don't ask multiple questions for the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that isnt working,

Comment: The object file isn't getting created.
Once that's done I'm sure it will work fine
Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Is the object file generated under src ? Try running this command from the command prompt and see if it works.

Comment: Jagnnath there is no object file created in the src directory.
That is why it is giving an error.
On the command line it also does not work as there is no object file
What should I do??

Comment: This problem is directly related to your previous problem. The `-M` and `-MM` switches cause gcc to output make rules *instead of an object file*. In your previous question you said that the makefile is the standard Eclipse creates, but I've never seen Eclipse do anything like this in the past. Can you detail the exact steps of making your project, a screenshot of your project's directory structure, as well as the contents of the makefile?